# MPAndroidChart Programmatically Change YAxis Range

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a way to programmatically change the YAxis Range of a chart in MPAndroidChart?

For instance, given the YAxis displays 0,10, I want to programmatically set the YAxis to -5,+5, but I want to do this several times during the course of an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport), I think you should give a try with a combination of :

- setVisibleYRangeMaximum(float maxYRange, AxisDependency axis): Sets the size of the area (range on the y-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. You also need to provide the axis this constraint should apply to.
- moveViewToY(float yValue, AxisDependency axis): Centers the viewport to the specified y-value on the provided y-axis (left or right).

Code for your example:

```
yourChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(10, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
yourChart.moveViewToY(0, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
yourChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: This code works for me. Did you use invalidate() on the chart to force redraw ? I edited my post.

Comment: Ah no, let me try :)

Comment: I think it works, once, but in a tight loop changing repeatedly, it doesn't work. I will mark as answer as it's the best accepted method, but looks to me like MPAndroidChart simply *does not support setting YAxis Range repeatedly* ... :/